# append is not working

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, append

I have parsed a json string and i want to use it in a tableview. when i try to append the json string into an array the append method is not working. Here is the code that i have used. Can anyone help me with this?

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

var userName = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.delegate =  self
    tableView.dataSource = self

    // 1
    let urlAsString = "http://demo.codeofaninja.com/tutorials/json-example-with-php/index.php"
    let url = NSURL(string: urlAsString)!
    let urlSession = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    //2
    let jsonQuery = urlSession.dataTaskWithURL(url, completionHandler: { data, response, error -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        }


        // 3
        do {
        let jsonResult = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
        /*let err: NSError!
        if (err != nil) {
            print("JSON Error \(err.localizedDescription)")
        }*/

        // 4
        //let fname: String! = jsonResult["firstname"] as! String
        //let lname: String! = jsonResult["lastname"] as! String
        //let usrname: String! = jsonResult["username"] as! String

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {

            if let users = jsonResult.objectForKey("Users") as? [[String:AnyObject]]
            {
                for user in users
                {
                    print("First Name:")
                    print(user["firstname"]!)
                    print("Last Name:")
                    print(user["lastname"]!)
                    print("User Name:")
                    let nameUser = user["username"]! as! String
                    print(nameUser)
                    self.userName.append(nameUser)
                    print("***************")
                }
            }

            //print(jsonResult["Users"]!)
            //print(lname)
            //print(usrname)
        })

        }
        catch {
            print("error");
        }
    })

        jsonQuery.resume()
    //self.userName.append("ganesh")
    // 5
    print(userName)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return userName.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as UITableViewCell!
    cell.textLabel?.text = userName[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    userName.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
    tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}
```

Comment: You have more than one append in the code. Exactly what is not working. The code doesn't compile? The app crashes? Do you have any errors you can post?

Comment: @Moriya in this line **self.userName.append(nameUser)**

Comment: what do you mean? Crash or it won't compile?

Comment: Or do you mean it never gets displayed in the tableView

Comment: @Moriya nameUser is not appended to the array userName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The append function works fine but you are filling the array in the background and never reloading the tableView when you have the data in the array

```
for user in users
{
    if let nameUser = user["username"] as? String {
        self.userName.append(nameUser)
    }    
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```

Try this inside the `if let users = jsonResult.objectForKey("Users") as? [[String:AnyObject]]` block

Answer (score 2):

You are appending right in the array,Just call `self.tableView.reloadData()` to refresh table view at the end of dispatch to show the data in the tableView.